# Improve runtime of python code with indexing and string concatenation

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I tried hard to improve the runtime of the following code snippet, which turned out to be the CPU-bottleneck in an asyncio-client package that I'm developing:

```
data = [''] * n
for i, ix in enumerate(indices):
    data[ix] = elements[i]
s = '\t'.join(data)
return s
```

What I do is basically very simple:

- `elements` is a list of `str` (each <= 7 characters) that I eventually write at specific positions into a tab-separated file.
- `indices` is a list of `int` giving the positions of each of the `elements` in the file
- If there is no element at a certain position, an empty string is inserted

I finally write the string into a text file using `aiofiles`.

So far, I tried to use a generator to create the data on the fly, as well as to use numpy for faster indexing, but with no success. Any idea how to make this code run faster would be great. Here is a reproducible example with timing:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

n = 1_000_000  # total number of items
k = 500_000  # number of elements to insert
elements = ['ade/gua'] * k  # elements to insert, <= 7 unicode characters
indices = list(range(0, n, 2))  # indices where to insert, sorted
assert len(elements) == len(indices)

# This is where I started
def baseline():
    data = [''] * n
    for i, ix in enumerate(indices):
        data[ix] = elements[i]
    s = '\t'.join(data)
    return s

# Generate values on the fly
def generator():
    def f():
        it = iter(enumerate(indices))
        i, ix = next(it)
        for j in range(n):
            if j == ix:
                yield elements[i]
                try:
                    i, ix = next(it)
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                yield ''
    s = '\t'.join(f())  # iterating though generation seem too costly
    return s

# Harness numpy
indices_np = np.array(indices)  # indices could also be numpy array
def numpy():
    data = np.full(n, '', dtype='<U7')
    data[indices_np] = elements  # this is faster with numpy
    s = '\t'.join(data)  # much slower. array2string or savetxt does not help
    return s

assert baseline() == generator() == numpy()

timeit.timeit(baseline, number=10)  # 0.8463204780127853
timeit.timeit(generator, number=10)  # 2.048296730965376 -> great job
timeit.timeit(numpy, number=10)  # 4.486689139157534 -> life sucks
```

## Edit 1

To address some of the points raised in the comments:

- I write the string `aiofiles.open(filename, mode='w') as file` and `file.write()`
- Indices can generally not be expressed as a range
- Indices can assumed to be always sorted at no extra cost.
- ASCII characters are sufficient

## Edit 2

Based on the answer of Mad Physicist, I tried the following code, with no success.

```
def buffer_plumbing():
m = len(elements) # total number of data points to insert
k = 7  # each element is 7 bytes long, only ascii 
total_bytes = n - 1 + m * 7  # total number of bytes for the buffer

# find out the number of preceeding gaps for each element
gap = np.empty_like(indices_np)
gap[0] = indices_np[0]  # that many gaps a the beginning
np.subtract(indices_np[1:], indices_np[:-1], out=gap[1:])
gap[1:] -= 1  # subtract one to get the gaps (except for the first)

# pre-allocate a large enough byte buffer
s = np.full(total_bytes , '\t', dtype='S1')

# write element into the buffer
start = 0
for i, (g, e) in enumerate(zip(gap, elements)):
    start += g
    s[start: start + k].view(dtype=('S', k))[:] = e
    start += k + 1
return s.tostring().decode('utf-8')

timeit.timeit(buffer_plumbing, number=10)  # 26.82
```

Comment: I have to ask, what does 'ade/cyt' mean?

Comment: You are relocating the string umpteen times when you do the join. Your best optimization may be to avoid constructing it in the first place. What is the final purpose of that string? Are you writing it somewhere?

Comment: @MadPhysicist `ade/cyt` refered to nucleotides (as was biologically wrong, btw). I write it to a text file.

Comment: Why don't you replace the `'ade/gua'` and other strings with integers. For example 1 for `'ade/gua'`, 2 for `'ade/cyt'`, etc... And with `data = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int64)` you do `data[ix] = elements[i]`. Or what is your expected output? How many combinations do you expect?

Comment: @Scotty1- The list of strings is the response from an API. I would be possible to recode the genotypes to another format, but that would probably just take longer.

Comment: Can you show how you write the string exactly. I think your biggest speedup will come from not concatenating the whole thing if you're writing it to a file.

Comment: Are `indices` something you could express as a range? If not, how big is the set of indices?

Comment: Also, not to nitpick too much, but your loop `for i, ix in enumerate(indices): data[ix] = elements[i]` would be less confusing, and possibly marginally faster, if written as `for i, e in zip(indices, elements): data[i] = e`.

Comment: Are `indices` always sorted?

Answer (score 2):

You can pre-sort your data, after converting it to a pair of numpy arrays. This will allow you to manipulate a single pre-existing buffer rather than copying strings over and over as you reallocate them. The difference between my suggestion and your attempt is that we will use [`ndarray.tobytes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) (or [`ndarray.tostring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html)) with the assumption that you only have ASCII characters. In fact, you can completely bypass the copy operation involved in converting into a `bytes` object by using [`ndarray.tofile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) directly.

If you have `elements` in-hand, you know that the total length of your line will be the combined length of the `elements` and `n-1` tab separators. The start of an element in the full string is therefore it's index (the number of tabs that precede it) plus the cumulative length of all the elements that come before it. Here is a simple implementation of a single-buffer fill using mostly Python loops:

```
lengths = np.array([len(e) for e in elements])
indices = np.asanyarray(indices)
elements = np.array(elements, dtype='S7')
order = np.argsort(indices)

elements = elements[order]
indices = indices[order]
lengths = lengths[order]

cumulative = np.empty_like(lengths)
cumulative[0] = 0
np.cumsum(lengths[:-1], out=cumulative[1:])
cumulative += lengths

s = np.full(cumulative[-1] + n - 1, '\t', dtype='S1')
for i, l, e in zip(cumulative, lengths, elements):
    s[i:i + l].view(dtype=('S', l))[:] = e
```

There are lots of possible optimizations to play with here, such as the possibility of allocating `s` using [`np.empty`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html#numpy.empty) and only filling in the required elements with tabs. This will be left as an excise for the reader.

Another possibility is to avoid converting `elements` to a numpy array entirely (it probably just wastes space and time). You can then rewrite the `for` loop as

```
for i, l, o in zip(cumulative, lengths, order):
    s[i:i + l].view(dtype=('S', l))[:] = elements[o]
```

You can dump the result into a `bytes` object with

```
s = s.tobytes()
```

OR

```
s = s.tostring()
```

You can write the result as-is to a file opened for binary writing. In fact, if you don't need a copy of the buffer in the form of a `bytes`, you can just write to the file directly:

```
s.tofile(f)
```

That will save you some memory and processing time.

In the same vein, you may be better off just writing to a file directly, piece by piece. This saves you not only the need to allocate the full buffer, but also the cumulative lengths. In fact, the only thing you need this way is the [`diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) of successive indices to tell you how many tabs to insert:

```
indices = np.asanyarray(indices)
order = np.argsort(indices)

indices = indices[order]

tabs = np.empty_like(indices)
tabs[0] = indices[0]
np.subtract(indices[1:], indices[:-1], out=tabs[1:])
tabs[1:] -= 1

for t, o in zip(tabs, order):
    f.write('\t' * t)
    f.write(elements[o])
f.write('\t' * (n - indices[-1] - 1))
```

This second approach has two major advantages besides the reduced amount of calculation. The first is that it works with unicode characters rather than ASCII only. The second is that it does not allocate any buffers besides strings of tabs, which should be extremely fast.

In both cases, having `elements` and `indices` sorted into ascending order by index will speed things up dramatically. The first case reduces to

```
lengths = np.array([len(e) for e in elements])
indices = np.asanyarray(indices)

cumulative = np.empty_like(lengths)
cumulative[0] = 0
np.cumsum(lengths[:-1], out=cumulative[1:])
cumulative += lengths

s = np.full(cumulative[-1] + n - 1, '\t', dtype='S1')
for i, l, e in zip(cumulative, lengths, elements):
    s[i:i + l].view(dtype=('S', l))[:] = e
```

And the second becomes just

```
indices = np.asanyarray(indices)

tabs = np.empty_like(indices)
tabs[0] = indices[0]
np.subtract(indices[1:], indices[:-1], out=tabs[1:])
tabs[1:] -= 1

for t, e in zip(tabs, elements):
    f.write('\t' * t)
    f.write(e)
f.write('\t' * (n - indices[-1] - 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. It tried the last approach, but I think there is a bug, because I need '\t' also between consecutive elements as a delimitier. Besides, this massively slows down everything du to the large number of calls to `file.write`.

Comment: I tried everything now and its just getting worse. Seems like time to surrender...

Comment: @dmy. I'll play with it some more once I'm on a desktop. This is interesting. Remember to include the I/O in your timing. That's likely to be a bigger bottleneck than the in-memory stuff.

Comment: I'm using asyncio for this reason so I *made* the CPU to be my bottleneck.

Comment: If you're writing to a file, you're writing to a file. Writing x number of bytes will take a fixed amount of time, which will generally only go up if you try to parallelize with other disk operations.

Comment: Yes, but writing to the file is much faster than the server can deliver its content. I basically have a queue for everything that goes to that file and a worker thread in the backgroud that reads from this queue and writes to the file.